# How to keep the position of the Angular select options with the field?

Tags: angular, angular-material

In using **ng2-google-charts** and **angular-material** the select list is below the chart while the control is above the chart. How do I keep these together?

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Continent</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="continents" (change)="onSelectContinent()">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let continent of continents | keyvalue" [value]="continent.key">{{continent.value}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The select list is ini *cdk-overlay-container* html element which is rendered outside of the *<app_root>* element.

The module imports

```
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a theme

Add

```
https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme
```

to the top of the styles.css file as described in [enter link description here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)